# How can I ignore files with no extension/suffix in vs code on a Mac?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know how to ignore most files in VScode as follows

```cpp
 "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.pdf": true,
        "**/*.out": true,
        "**/*.exe": true,
        "**/Music": true 
    },
```

But I also want to ignore files with no extension or suffix, for example the filename is `smartPoint` (which is generated after I run file `smartPoint.cpp` in VScode). Is there any way I can ignore this kind of Unix file on a Mac?

[image: Picture describe]

Answer (score -1):

Since you have generated files with the same basename I was hoping that some form of [hiding derived files](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_hiding-derived-javascript-files) would work. Example for typescript/javascript:

```
 "files.exclude": {
   **/*.js: { "when": "$(basename).ts" }
 }
```

But what to put in the key `**/.js`?  I tried

```
   "**/*": { "when": "$(basename).cpp }      // doesn't work
   "**/$(basename)": { "when": "$(basename).ts" }  // doesn't work
   "**/[^.]*": { "when": "$(basename).ts" }  // doesn't work
   "**/*[^.]*": { "when": "$(basename).ts" }  // doesn't work
   "**/*[^.]{1,10}": { "when": "$(basename).ts" }  // doesn't work
```

I really thought some version of the last would work - excluding files with no extension - but no.

**WARNING**: *dirty hack* follows.  As a lark I tried

```
"**/[^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.]": {"when": "$(basename).cpp"},
```

since `smartPoint` has 10 characters.  **That works !!**  But not for `new` - 3 characters.  But you can have both:

```
"**/[^.][^.][^.]": {"when": "$(basename).cpp"},   // works on 3 character file names
"**/[^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.]": {"when": "$(basename).cpp"},  // works on 10
```

so yes, unless someone comes up with a better solution, you could include all the versions you need for the number of characters (for 1...10, etc.) you might have.

Ugly, but simple.