How Can You Search VS-Code Workspace Excluding The Non-File-Type Files?
In VS-Code's Search-All Files-To-Include, how are you supposed to write-up searching in only any real files?
In a shared project, I've got files like: thisIsAFile, 1234abcd, old_new_file-1. 
Say I'm looking for: keyword "keyword"; in file-types including: *.java, *.properties, *.yaml, *.py, *.js; and directories including: ~/project/name/files/source, ..else/where/data/base/data, ./locally/working/space. These directories have all been added into the VS-Code Workspace.
I tried writing something like just typing in document-editor/writer-style ~/*.* or other best guesses I tried.
My try on didn't work for RegEx (Regular Expression) ~/**/*\.* and other variations. Does someone know how to search any (and all) the regular files with actual file-types without listing them all out?

duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/60393786/11107541

Mine doesn't have these files as git-ignored.
